# How to Get Data When Using first() Equivalent in Laravel Model?

Tags: php, database, laravel, model, controller

I use Laravel version 5.7 and want to get data from the database. I tried using `$genre->name` but it didn't work, and also I tried `$genre->toArray()` but got another error.

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\genre;

class Mins extends Controller
{
    public function genget($data)
    {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $genre = genre::where('name', $value)->first();
            echo $genre->name;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the data in `$data` when I `var_dump`.

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(6) "Comedy" [1]=> string(3) 
    "Action" [2]=> string(8) "Bad" [3]=> string(7) "Good" }
```

I'm getting the following error (echo in the controller):

> "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object"

However, when I try to do `dd($genre->name)` in the controller I did get the data.

**Model**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;  

class genre extends Model  
{
      protected $fillable = ['name', 'slug'];
}
```

I'm also trying:

```
$genre = genre::where('name', $value)->first()->toArray();
dd($genre);
```

Response:

```
array:6 [▼
  "id" => 1
  "name" => "Comedy"
  "slug" => "comedy"
  "created_at" => "2019-01-11 15:02:31"
  "updated_at" => "2019-01-11 15:02:31"
  "deleted_at" => null
]
```

But when I call specified value like `echo $g['name'];` I get the error:

> "Call to a member function toArray() on null"

I try to change the `$value` using a string like:

```
$genre = genre::where('name', 'Comedy')->first();
```

This works perfectly, does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: What do you get it you do `dd($genre);`?

Comment: What's the error being thrown?

Comment: @Mozammil "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object"

Comment: That would lead me to believe that you don't have a row in the database where `name` is equal to `$value`.

Comment: @elandhricky please add the answers to the comments by editing the question. It's clear from the error that $genre is null. Meaning there is no entry for the name you tried with

Comment: @RossWilson @Indra when I do `dd($genre);` it got something like this `genre {  #fillable: array:2 [▶] #connection: "mysql" }`, btw when I try `dd($genre->name);` I got the data, but when I try `echo $genre->nae;` it got error "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object"

Comment: Please can you add your `genre` model to your question?

Comment: @RossWilson here the model : class genre extends Model
{
      protected $fillable = ['name', 'slug'];
}

Comment: As @Indra mentioned earlier, in future please can you add code to your post rather than in the comments.

Comment: @Indra I'm not have the answer yet

Comment: @RossWilson ah sure

Comment: also can you put the class name in capital letters? Try referring to the psr standard when you code

Comment: Are you echoing your code in a controller or in a blade file?

Comment: @elandhricky answer to the questions we add in the comments need to be posted by editing your initial question. That way the next person who stumbles upon this doesn't have to go though all these comments

Comment: @RossWilson I'm trying to echo in the controller

Comment: @Indra I see, thanks a lot

Comment: Could you `dd($genre->toArray());` right before your echo statement?

Comment: Also, where are you initializing `$value`?

Comment: @Mozammil `$value = 'comedy'`

Comment: Could you edit your answer with the result of `dd($genre->toArray());`? Add it right before your echo statement.

Comment: @Mozammil Updated

Comment: `first()` returns null if no records are found. So make sure that `$genre` is not null before you attempt to do anything with it.

Comment: @aynber I try `dd` the `$genre` it's not null like above but when I try to `echo` the errror come

Comment: Is this in a loop? Or one at a time? You seem to be getting different values every time you comment.

Comment: I have a feeling you are not showing us your actual code..

Comment: @Mozammil  well I update it

Comment: @aynber updated

Comment: Yep, in a loop. The dump you're getting is for when it does find a result. The error is when it's not finding a result. So add an if-check after you retrieve the model. `if($genre) { echo $genre->name; }`

Comment: @aynber I see know. man, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Check for empty result :

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value)
{
    $genre = genre::where('name', $value)->first(); 

    if ($genre)
    {
        echo $genre->name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, with the code in your example, I would suggest checking to see if the model actually exists before doing anything with it, this way you're not going to have an error thrown when it doesn't exist. When using `first()` it is either going to return the `Eloquent` model or `null` so an easy check would be something like:

```
$genre = genre::where('name', $value)->first();

if ($genre) {
   echo $genre->name; 
}
```

That being said, performing a query inside a loop is pretty inefficient and considered bad practice. In this case you'd be better of using [whereIn()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#where-clauses) and then looping through the results:

```
public function genget($data)
{
    $genres = genre::whereIn('name', $data)->get();

    foreach ($genres as $genre) {
        echo $genre->name;
    }
}
```

This way you're only ever performing one query (instead of 4 like in your example) and you won't have to worry about them existing when you loop through them.

---

**NB**

This isn't essential but I would strongly recommend following the PSR's, specifically in this case [PSR-1 - Namespace and Class Names](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/#3-namespace-and-class-names) so you're `genre` class should be `Genre` e.g.

**class declaration**: `class Genre` (not `class genre`)

**class file name**: `Genre.php` (not `genre.php`)

**class usage**: `Genre::someMethod()` (`genre::someMethod()`)